# ora-03001 unimplemented feature when running select in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, ojdbc

i tried to run following select query on an oracle 11g from java (using thin driver) when i got that error code back.
my question is why i get this error? i assume it must be an issue with the thin driver but i cant figure out what it could be since it does support select querys... pls help me out !

`java.sql.SQLException:   ora-03001 unimplemented feature`

ora version:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.1.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

the query was:

```
    query = "select e.eq_nr as \"Eqiptmentnummer\", f.file_name as \"Dateiname\" e.adress as \"Adresse\","
            + " e.city as \"Ort\", e.county as \"Bundesland\", e.zip_code as \"PLZ\","
            + " e.manufacturer as \"Hersteller\" f.doc_info as \"DOC INFO\""
            + " from elevators e join files f on(e.eq_nr = (select eq_nr from file_links where file_id = f.file_id))";
```

using preparedStatement and executeQuery:

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.getCon().prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

i ran this query in sql developer and it gave me this output(all elevators and their associated files), which is correct:

```
eq_nr | file_name     |      adress    | city  |county| zip  |manufaturer|  note
1000    testname1.pdf   somestreet 12   Vienna  Vienna  1200    OTIS    test insert brown 1
1000    testname2.pdf   somestreet 12   Vienna  Vienna  1200    OTIS    test insert brown 2
1000    testname4.pdf   somestreet 12   Vienna  Vienna  1200    OTIS    test insert brown 4
1001    testname.pdf    somestreet 123  Vienna  Vienna  1200    KONE    test insert brown
1001    testname3.pdf   somestreet 123  Vienna  Vienna  1200    KONE    test insert brown 3
1001    testname5.pdf   somestreet 123  Vienna  Vienna  1200    KONE    test insert brown5 
1001    testname6.pdf   somestreet 123  Vienna  Vienna  1200    KONE    test insert brown 6
```

asd select * from elevators:

```
elevator id|         adress        | city | county | zip  | manufacturer
1000        somestreet 12   Vienna  Vienna  1200    OTIS
1001        somestreet 123  Vienna  Vienna  1200    KONE
```

select * from files:

```
[FILE_ID]  [FILE_NAME]  [FILE_PATH]     [FILE_TYPE] [LAST_CHANGED]         [ARCHIVE_FLAG][DOC_INFO]
77       [testname.pdf] [C:\testname.pdf]   [pdf]   27.02.14 19:08:39,720000000  0      [test insert brown]
987     [testname1.pdf] [C:\testname1.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:08:55,195000000  0      [test insert brown 1]
76523   [testname2.pdf] [C:\testname2.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:09:09,735000000  0      [test insert brown 2]
123323  [testname3.pdf] [C:\testname3.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:09:35,912000000  0      [test insert brown 3]
1232    [testname4.pdf] [C:\testname4.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:09:49,219000000  0      [test insert brown 4]
8888212 [testname5.pdf] [C:\testname5.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:10:08,267000000  0      [test insert brown5 ]
5678    [testname6.pdf] [C:\testname6.pdf]  [pdf]   27.02.14 19:10:22,213000000  0      [test insert brown 6]
```

select * from file_links:

```
eq_ nr     file_id  valid
1000    76523   0
1000    1232    0
1000    987 0
1001    5678    0
1001    8888212 0
1001    123323  0
1001    77  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be just a copy paste issue. In every query you posted you are missing a comma between

```
f.file_name as \"Dateiname\" e.adress as \"Adresse\",
```

but the edit above does not.

```
f.file_name as \"Dateiname\", e.adress as \"Adresse\",
```

Can it be that simple? ;)

Comment: i cant belive i failed to see that obvious mistake.. this error pulled my focus away from such issues.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the join/subselect combination is not standard. I would suggest something like

```
query = "select e.eq_nr as \"Eqiptmentnummer\", f.file_name as \"Dateiname\" e.adress as \"Adresse\","
        + " e.city as \"Ort\", e.county as \"Bundesland\", e.zip_code as \"PLZ\","
        + " e.manufacturer as \"Hersteller\" f.doc_info as \"DOC INFO\""
        + " from elevators e"
        + " join files f on (e.eq_nr = f.eq_nr)"
        + " where e.eq_nr in ("
        + "   select f.eq_nr"
        + "   from files f"
        + "   join file_links fl"
        + "   where fl.file_id = f.file_id"
        + ")";
```

**EDIT**

```
query = "select e.eq_nr as \"Eqiptmentnummer\", f.file_name as \"Dateiname\", e.adress as \"Adresse\", e.city as \"Ort\", e.county as \"Bundesland\", e.zip_code as \"PLZ\",  e.manufacturer as \"Hersteller\", f.doc_info as \"DOC INFO\""
    + " from elevators e"
    + " join file_links fl on (e.eq_id = fl.eq_id)"
    + " join files f on (f.file_id = fl.file_id)";
```

Comment: there is no f.eq_nr [join files f on (e.eq_nr = F.EQ_NR)], its a many to many relationship, thats why i have the file_links table where eq_nr and f_id are both primary keys.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "not standard"? i suggest you are reffering to thin? because as said in the question this exact query works in sql developer

Comment: It was the solemn SQL structure I thought I can't verify in my head - if this is standard, sorry!

Comment: gave me an ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: didnt have time to check it  just ran it, worked :) thnaks, but still, i dont get why my query didnt work

Comment: i´ll leave it unanswerd, since this is a workaround not the actual answer

Comment: I would appreciate it, if you could find any SQL grammar allowing this "join on column by sub select" statement, I quickly checked and found none - perhaps it's an Oracle (SQLDewveloper) thing?